# The effect of the coefficient of the derivative part in PID control

Tags: pid-controller

I am learning about control systems, specifically PID control.

I am a little confused by the coefficient in front of the derivative term. My lecturer said a positive coefficient for the derivative part results in reaching our desired motor output faster. I struggle to believe him because if the coefficient is positive I imagine two things happening:

First is that, initially as our control action increases, our rate of change of error is negative and the derivative contribution to our control is negative. This slows down the rate at which we increase our control effort resulting in us reaching the desired motor output later.

Second is that if we overshoot our desired motor output then the derivative term becomes positive and pushes in the opposite direction we want our control effort to go to reach our desired motor output.

It seems to me that the inclusion of the derivative term with a positive coefficient just opposes the direction we want to the rate of change of motor output to go always.  Surely I am misunderstanding something.  Does anybody see the conceptual mistake I am making?

[image]

Comment: Draw the block diagram you refer to. I've seen block diagrams for PID controller with negative gain stages after the derivative term and also without. Your analysis is correct though; the derivative term is like a slew rate limiter and thus prevents excessive overshoot.

Comment: Okay thank you that is good to hear. I have added the block diagram

Answer (score 0):

"... a positive coefficient for the derivative part"

That's a first time I see a mention of a *sign of the coefficient*.
AFAIK the coefficient, i.e. Kd is always positive. It is the derivative *term* that can be either positive or negative depending on the rate of change of an error.

Furthermore, the sign of the derivative term depends on which side of the setpoint the process variable is, same as P and I terms.

In either case, let's look at the actual formula. Assuming that setpoint does not change:

E0 = S - P0; E1 = S - P1 => dE = - (P1 - P0) = - dP

So, if S > P then both proportional and integral terms are usually positive. Normally, these two should result in process variable growing, trying to reach setpoint. The derivative term, however, is an *inversion* of process differential. So, the faster the process variable grows, the more *negative* derivative term becomes, dampening this growth. You can see the same effect when S < P, only all signs in the equation will be reversed.

It is interesting to note that if you introduce external disturbance stronger than current command and force process variable backwards, then the sign of the derivative term will also change, so instead of dampening it will actually help P and I move in the desired direction.

Now, that out of the way, I think you misunderstood a crucial point in your teacher's statement. "reaching our desired motor output faster" **does not mean getting process variable to setpoint momentarily**. There is a term in control theory - "*Settling time*". This is a time it takes a system to reach *stable* control output (and coincidentally, stable process value).

In your example, if motor output reaches the desired value but then overshoots it, it did not actually "reach desired output", did it? It has to get back, potentially overshooting it again and so on. Only when the output is stable you can say your system has reached desired state. By dampening the control signal derivative term indeed can reduce this time significantly, so your teacher was absolutely correct.